# Conda showing two versions of requests library

Tags: python, conda, miniconda

I'm new to conda and seeing something strange but I don't actually know if it's a problem or not.

I'm currently in the root environment. At some point I was trying to install pip in another environment, but accidentally just ran `pip install requests`. This seems to have installed it in my root environment:

```
$ conda list | grep requests
requests                  2.12.4                   py36_0  
requests                  2.13.0                    <pip>
```

And it looks like the pip version is what's getting picked up when I run python:

```
$ python
Python 3.6.0 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:22:00) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests; requests.__version__
'2.13.0'
```

My guess is that having two versions of the same package lying around is going to cause headaches later. Then my assumption was that I'd be better off keeping the non-pip version, so I tried this:

```
$ pip uninstall requests
[asks for confirmation, say yes]
$ conda list
[traceback, which I can post if helpful. Summary is:]
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Then `pip install requests` brings me back to square 1 (having both versions of requests).

Finally, I want to know how to prevent this from happening again. According to the [docs](https://conda.io/docs/test-drive.html#managing-environments), if I want to use pip to install a package in a conda environment, I should:

1. Activate the conda environment where you want to install the package
2. run `pip install whatever`
3. It should show up in `conda list` for the current environment.

However, this isn't working for me - the installed package shows up under `conda list --name root` rather than in the current environment.

---

So, handful of questions:

1. Is it a problem to have two copies of `requests` in my conda root?
2. If this is a problem, how do I fix it?
3. How do I use pip within a conda environment?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Is it a problem to have two copies of requests in my conda root?

Probably.

> 2. If this is a problem, how do I fix it?

In my testing, `conda remove` followed by `pip uninstall` does the trick.  (After which you can just re-install requests using only conda this time.)  But if something goes wrong, remove `.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests-2.13.0.dist-info`.  That seemed to work for me.

FWIW, I was only able to reproduce the double-install by installing with pip *first*, then installing again with conda.

> 3. How do I use pip within a conda environment?

Your summary in the OP is correct.  Just activate the conda environment and use pip as you normally would.  My rule of thumb is to install packages with `conda` if they are available, and resort to `pip` otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply -- but when i try to `conda remove requests` I get: `CondaEnvironmentError: Environment error: cannot remove python, pycosat, ruamel_yaml, conda, openssl, requests from root environment`

Comment: Oops, I was experimenting with a non-root environment. (I should have known you would see that error... [I put it there!](https://github.com/conda/conda/pull/1153/commits/f8f385d718cefae8d2c3a16a9258461aed490f8e)) OK, did you try the 'if something goes wrong...' suggestion? That is, just remove `the dist-info` folder and see if the 'pip' version disappears from the list.

Comment: Another trick: When something is really wrong with your root environment, you might have to just start over from scratch with a separate conda install.  But sometimes you can use the separate install to fix the first one.  I would guess that `conda remove -p /path/to/original-root-env requests` would work, if run it from a *new* conda install.  Then you can re-install `requests` again.